# Working with doctrine and relations, how?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to make a method for activate users through a token, but i'm a little lost about how can i verify using doctrine 2 and relations.

Here you can see an screen of my database relations.

[image]

This is my user entity

```
.............
/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Token", mappedBy="username", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $token;

    public function getToken(): ?Token
    {
        return $this->token;
    }

    public function setToken(?Token $token): self
    {
        $this->token = $token;

        // set (or unset) the owning side of the relation if necessary
        $newUsername = $token === null ? null : $this;
        if ($newUsername !== $token->getUsername()) {
            $token->setUsername($newUsername);
        }

        return $this;
    }
.............
```

This is my token entity

```
.............
/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="token", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $username;

    public function getUsername(): ?User
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(?User $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }
.............
```

The application works as expected when i register any user and the email has been sent.

In other project without realtions in the token ( saving the token in the same table as user ) i didn't have any problem making the method as shown below:

```
.............
/**
     * @Route("/activation/{token}/", name="activation/", methods={"GET"}))
     */
    public function activation(Request $request, User $user, $token)
    {
        $token = $request->attributes->get('token');
        $update = $user->getToken();
        $user->setToken(null);
        $user->setActive(true);
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();
        return $this->render(
            'emails/confirmation.html.twig');
    }
.............
```

But with this method i'm receiving the following error Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter.

Anyone have any idea?

Thanks for your time.

Kind regards.

..............................

EDIT1:
ERROR: Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "token".

CODE:

```
    /**
    * @Route("/activation/{pledge}/", name="activation/", methods={"GET"}))
    */
    public function activation(Request $request, Token $token, $pledge)
    {
        $user = $pledge->getUsername();
        if ( null === $user) {

        }
        $user->setToken(null);
        $user->setActive(true);
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();
        return $this->render(' emails/confirmation.html.twig');
    }
}
```

EDIT2: SOLUTION

```
/**
    * @Route("/activation/{token}/", name="activation/", methods={"GET"}))
    */
    public function activation(Request $request, Token $pledge, $token)
    {
        $token = $request->attributes->get('token');
        $user = $pledge->getUsername();
        if ( null === $pledge) {

        }
        $pledge->setToken(null);
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($pledge);
        $entityManager->flush();
        return $this->render('emails/confirmation.html.twig');
    }
```

Comment: Which version of symfony are you using? Next to that - are you sure you've pasted the whole error? There should be a double-quoted parameter name after the `... for parameter` at the end of the message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The error is for any "entity" that i try to pass as parameter: Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "token". in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your old setup the `User` entity could be matched by ParamConverter because, as you wrote, there was a `token` field in it.

Now the `token` field is a part of the `Token` entity, so what you can do is match the `Token` entity and get the user from it:

```php
public function activation(Request $request, Token $token)
{
    $user = $token->getUsername();
    if (null === $user) {
        // Here handle the situation with the token already used to activate a user
    }
    $user->setToken(null);
    $user->setActive(true);
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entityManager->persist($user);
    $entityManager->flush();

    return $this->render( 'emails/confirmation.html.twig');

}

 ....
```

Comment: Hi Michal. Thanks for your comment. i get the same error, in this case Token $token is my entity, and $pledge is the token that i catch through the request:    /**
........ In this case the error is : Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "token". Check EDIT1: ERROR:  thanks

Comment: HI again. It's just as you said, just i had to change some things, like nullable=true in my entity and some params. Check edit2 for resolution. Thanks! cheers